# How to disable focus for the first input in a Primefaces Dialog?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, focus

I have a Dialog in my Page, which contains a input field **(Date, Calendar)** . The problem is that the calendar opens directly after opening the dialog, because the focus is set on the first input.

Is there a way to disable focus in Primefaces?

Comment: Can you just set the tab order to a different field so that a different field has focus?

Comment: there is only one inputField :(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can change the default behavior;

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29050

You can always override default behaviors of widgets, for example to prevent calendar focus on dialog opening;

```
PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog.prototype.applyFocus = function() {
  var firstInput = this.jq.find(':not(:submit):not(:button):input:visible:enabled:first');
  if(!firstInput.hasClass('hasDatepicker')) {
      firstInput.focus();
  }
}
```

original code is;

```
PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog.prototype.applyFocus = function() {
  this.jq.find(':not(:submit):not(:button):input:visible:enabled:first').focus();
}
```

If you put your override after PrimeFaces resources then your applyFocus implementation will be picked up and used instead.

I'd suggest creating a js file like primefaces-overrides.js and put things like this inside, one disadvantage though since you are coding against low level apis, you need to watch out for regressions during migrations although we aim to keep backward compatibility as much as we can.

Comment: when multiple date-picker how to resolve same issue ? it's work fine on one date-picker @CagatayCivici

Answer (score 7):

Something simpler could be set focus by default in another input you have.

```
<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Users" focus="savebtn" widgetVar="txtName">
```

If you are calling from another file

```
<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Users" focus="savebtn" widgetVar="formRegUsers:txtName">
```

Comment: Focus can also be set to the form component.

Answer (score 2):

Another trick to fix this issue:

I have added a text input as first input of the dialog in my dialog:

```
<p:dialog id="myDialogId" widgetVar="myDialog"....

  <p:inputText id="fixForFocusProblem"/>

  <p:calendar ...
  ..
</p:dialog>
```

And when showing the dialog I call this:

```
$('#myForm\\:fixForFocusProblem').show();
myDialog.show(); 
$('#myForm\\:fixForFocusProblem').hide();
```

This way the focus gets on the input text which gets immediately unvisible.

Not so nice but it works without visually disturbing.

Answer (score 0):

This will also do:

```
<p:dialog onShow="$(document.activeElement).blur()" ...>
```

Or Primefaces jQuery

```
<p:dialog onShow="jQuery(document.activeElement).blur()" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this script in your .xhtml :

```
    PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog.prototype.applyFocus = function () {
        var firstInput = this.jq.find(':not(:submit):not(:button):input:visible:enabled:first');
        if (!firstInput.hasClass('hasDatepicker')) {
            firstInput.focus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is different here compared to the code in the accepted answer?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a datePicker I suggest to use it like this :

```
<p:datePicker showOnFocus="false" showIcon="true" ... />
```

Comment: It indeed works but the datePicker popup overlay is completely disabled afterwards.

Comment: Just click the icon if you want the popup. Most of the time I use 'mask="true"' to improve data input speed.