# Avoid/Disable autojump to inputfield

Tags: javascript, html, primefaces

I have a problem, concerning the html input tag or primefaces p:input.
Why is the cursor ALWAYS auto jumping into the inputfield. My pages height is high so that you need to scroll down. The inputfield is at the end of the page and the cursor jumps automaticly (onload) to the end of the page into the inputfield. how can i avoid this auto jump?

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:commandButton oncomplete="PF('dlgG').show();" value="Open"
        id="button" update="dialog" partialSubmit="true" />
    <p:dialog appendToBody="true" appendTo="@(body)" modal="true"
        id="dialog" resizable="false" closeOnEscape="true" widgetVar="dlgG"
        showEffect="drop" hideEffect="drop">

        <div
            style="width: 90%; height: 100px; background: black; margin-bottom: 1000px;color:red;" id="demo"></div>

        <p:inputTextarea autoResize="true" rows="3" cols="100"
            value="#{auftragBean.comment}" id="inputBox" />
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'why' is a documentation and [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/focus.xhtml) question (aka RTFM ;-)):

The `p:dialog` has a `focus` attribute as can be read on [page 183 of the 5.3 documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf#183)

> `focus   null    String    Defines which component to apply focus`

And on [page 184](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf#184) it says:

> **Focus**
>
> Dialog applies focus on **first visible input** on show by default which is useful for user friendliness
>   however in some cases this is not desirable. Assume the first input is a popup calendar and opening
>   the dialog shows a popup calendar. To customize default focus behavior, use focus attribute.

Preventing it can most likely be be achieved by adding a dummy input at the top with no reference to values and give that a 'blur()' in its onfocus attribute. But you can also use the solution from [this other stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761275/how-to-disable-focus-for-the-first-input-in-a-primefaces-dialog) (the not accepted solution with the `onShow`)

Comment: Thanks for the share!