# How to override PrimeFaces focus behaviour?

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I'm using <p:focus> in <p:dialog>, but I need to override the function <p:focus> does by default. How can I achieve that? I suppose there is something like the answer of the following question:

[How to disable focus for the first input in a Primefaces Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761275/how-to-disable-focus-for-the-first-input-in-a-primefaces-dialog/15775427)
Many thanks for any help!

Comment: by looking at the source of the component and override the behaviour, most likely some javascript in this case

Comment: In that answers there shoud be everything you need, what are you still missing?